# Comparing Date to Data-Connection Date in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date, format, number-formatting

I'm attempting to compare dates generated in a worksheet "Test" with dates in another worksheet that are generated from a database connection in worksheet "360".  I cannot seem to get the dates that are generated in the "Test" worksheet to have an actual value of "MM/DD/YYYY".  In other words, I cannot get the actual value in the cells to be "05/05/2018", it always generates it as "5/5/2018".  I first attempted to change the format of it, but this just changes the format and not the data.

The dates in the "360" database connection get pulled in as text as "MM/DD/YYYY" and in order to compare the dates from both worksheets to see when then are a match I need to format the dates in the "Test" worksheet to be "MM/DD/YYYY".  Does anyone know how to generate an ACTUAL value of "MM/DD/YYYY" considering the code below?

```
Sub SMALLDATETEST()

Workbooks("Receiving Research.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets("Test").Activate

iAddDays = 0

For iIncrementer = 1 To 75

    'Generating Dates
    Cells(iIncrementer, 1).Value = DateAdd("d", iAddDays, "05/01/2018")
    Cells(iIncrementer, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    iAddDays = iAddDays + 1

Next iIncrementer

'Comparing Dates
For iIncrementer = 1 To 75
    Worksheets("Test").Activate

    sCurrentTestDate = Cells(iIncrementer, 1).Value
    Worksheets("360").Activate

    'MsgBox sCurrentTestDate

    For iNewIncrementer = 3 To 20

        sCurrent360Date = Cells(iNewIncrementer, 19).Value

       'If the dates match put a "Y" in the B column
        If Trim(sCurrentTestDate) = Trim(sCurrent360Date) Then
            Worksheets("Test").Activate
            Cells(iIncrementer, 2).Value = "Y"
        End If

    Next iNewIncrementer

Next iIncrementer

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional column and used the following to convert the text in the "Test" worksheet to an ACTUAL format of "MM/DD/YYYY":

```
Cells(iIncrementer, 2).Formula = "=TEXT(A" & iIncrementer & ",""mm/dd/yyyy"")"
```

So the complete working code:

```
Sub DateTestingBD()

Workbooks("Receiving Research.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets("Test").Activate

iAddDays = 0

For iIncrementer = 1 To 75

    Cells(iIncrementer, 1).Value = DateAdd("d", iAddDays, "05/01/2018")
    Cells(iIncrementer, 2).Formula = "=TEXT(A" & iIncrementer & ",""mm/dd/yyyy"")"
    iAddDays = iAddDays + 1

Next iIncrementer

For iIncrementer = 1 To 75
Worksheets("Test").Activate

    sCurrentTestDate = Cells(iIncrementer, 2).Value
    Worksheets("360").Activate

    For iNewIncrementer = 3 To 20

        sCurrent360Date = Cells(iNewIncrementer, 19).Value

        If Trim(sCurrentTestDate) = Trim(sCurrent360Date) Then
            Worksheets("Test").Activate
            Cells(iIncrementer, 3).Value = "Y"
        End If

    Next iNewIncrementer

Next iIncrementer

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

True dates are nothing more than a long integer representing the number of days since 31-Dec-1899. It doesn't matter whether you are comparing 5/5/2018, 05/05/2018 or 43,225. They are exactly the same thing as far as [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) is concerned.

What isn't the same is text-that-looks-like-a-date. These are strings and the basic rules of string comparison apply; text-that-looks-like-a-date will never be equal to a real date.

In this case, you have two options:

1. Convert the dates in each worksheet to text-that-looks-like-a-date in identical format masks. This isn't considered 'best practice' as the dates become useless text labels.

   ```
   'on the worksheet
   =text(a1, "mm/dd/yyyy;@")

   ' in vba
   Cells(iIncrementer, 1).NumberFormat = "@" '<~~ set text format first
   Cells(iIncrementer, 1).Value = Format(DateAdd("d", iAddDays, dateserial(2018, 5, 1)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
   ```
2. Convert the dates in each worksheet to true dates. This is the preferred method as the dates can be used in further calculations.
   You can quickly convert entire columns of text-that-looks-like-dates into true dates with Text-to-Columns.